# How do I hide the program playback control when adjusting volumes in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

It is getting annoy because when the mouse hover over it, it would stay there for a few more seconds and blocking the contents I am viewing. If anyone know if I can disable it. Thanks.

[the block at right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a165Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I use this program, [3RVX](https://3rvx.com/).

3RVX provides custom volume on-screen displays (OSD) that disable the Windows 10 one, and it can be used to show no OSD at all when adjusting volumes.

It also allows you to attatch custom hotkeys to key-combos and media buttons to enable/disable the OSD and execute other media-related actions.

My primary use for it is to allow me to adjust the volume in 1% increments instead of the Windows forced 2%. Good luck!